# Infinite loop while calling function in heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath, heightforrowatindexpath

I am trying to call a function in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` which hide and show view inside that cell but I created an infinite loop unwillingly. Please point out what is the problem and how I can solve that.

function in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"indexrow = %ld \n pre = %d\n sel = %d \n",(long)[indexPath row],previousselectedcell,selectedcell);
    if([indexPath row] == previousselectedcell){       
        return 60;
    }
    else if ([indexPath row] == selectedcell) {    
        NSLog(@"height toggle= %@",toggle);
        [self ViewToggle:tableView IndexPath:indexPath Do:@"true"];
        return 180;
    }
    else
    {
        return 60;
    }
}
```

Function Definition

```
-(void)ViewToggle:(UITableView *)tableView IndexPath:(id)myindexPath Do:Toggle{
    InterestTableViewCell *cell = (InterestTableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myindexPath];
    if([Toggle isEqualToString:@"true"]){
        cell.ContainerView.hidden=NO;
    }
    else{
        cell.ContainerView.hidden=YES;
    }  
}
```

Comment: why you call ViewToggle method in heightForRowAtIndexPath instead of didselectrowindexpath. I want to understand your logic of view show and hide .

Comment: heightForRowAtIndexPath will be called  number of rows for each section

Comment: Please confirm how many section you have , because you have check section with indexrow in heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Please stop capitalising your variable names.

Comment: @SantuC my problem is that in didSelectRowAtIndexPath I can modify content(hide,show) of the current selected cell but not on the previously selected cell. I have to hide the content from previously selected cell and show content in current selected cell.

Comment: In didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can do what you like. But then there is also didDeselectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Please check below answer , its possible with  didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
InterestTableViewCell *cell = (InterestTableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myindexPath];
```

You are trying to get cell from table. But cell still not created. So you return to cell creation

heightForRowAtIndexPath is not a good place for configure cell content. It is better to do it in 
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
 method

Comment: yes I did that previously but my problem is that in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I can modify content(hide,show) of the current selected cell but not on the previously selected cell. I have to hide the content from previously selected cell and show content in current selected cell.

Comment: oh that haven't in my mind thanks will try and get back to you

Comment: Please see my answer, which does not require you to keep a note of the previously selected cell. The answer above will also not reset a cell's hidden state when cells are re-used as you scroll the table view.

Answer (score 1):

`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` should only be used for returning the height of the row. `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is a more appropriate place for your hiding logic:

Add the following to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` instead:

```
cell.ContainerView.hidden = (indexPath.row != selectedcell);
```

And call `[tableView reloadData]` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` after you've updated `selectedcell`.

You should also consider storing an `NSIndexPath` rather than an integer, as `nil` can represent that no selection has been made.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly looking at the problem of your infinite loop, the problem seems to be that `InterestTableViewCell *cell = (InterestTableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myindexPath];` is calling `heightForRowAtIndexPath` in the process of creating a new cell object.

I would highly recommend reusing `UITableViewCell`'s.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, your delegate methods should do what they are supposed to do and nothing else. This method should calculate the height of the cell and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Define in header -

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSIndexPath *oldIndex;
```

Please try below code instead of heightForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (self.oldIndex)
    {
        [self ViewToggle:tableView IndexPath:self.oldIndex Do:@"false"];
    }


    [self ViewToggle:tableView IndexPath:indexPath Do:@"true"];
    self.oldIndex=indexPath;

}
```